# How make sticky header for tabs with scroll position?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, sticky, scroll-position

I need sticky header tab **from start spot until end of the tab section**. like this [site](https://esam.ir/item/25405446/%D9%84%D9%BE-%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%BE-%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%B4%DB%8C%D8%A8%D8%A7-core-i7-t451) 
Currently, by using eventListener on the scroll, I made it possible for the header to become sticky, but I have several problems:

1. The scroll remains sticky after the tab section is finished
2. When I scroll the page again the tab stickiness to the top is not removed
   Where is the problem in my code?

this is my code in [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-blackburn-nmmmgw?file=/src/page/ProductPage/Product.jsx)

Answer (score 0):

You can show loading, until all the pages are loaded

Comment: thanks but this problem is not related to the page loading

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just put the header inside the section you want it to be sticky and add `position:sticky; top:0;` to the header.

```css
.container {
  background: gray;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <h1 class="sticky">Sticky</h1>
  <div>
    <h1>div 1</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non error at Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non error at Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non error at Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
      elit. Non error at hic dolore aspernatur impedit dolorem similique incidunt pariatur! Atque adipisci fugiat aperiam qui excepturi doloremque, quaerat quisquam similique molestiae. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non error
      at hic dolore aspernatur impedit dolorem similique incidunt pariatur! Atque adipisci fugiat aperiam qui excepturi doloremque, quaerat quisquam similique molestiae.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>div 2</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non error at Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non error at Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non error at Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
      elit. Non error at hic dolore aspernatur impedit dolorem similique incidunt pariatur! Atque adipisci fugiat aperiam qui excepturi doloremque, quaerat quisquam similique molestiae. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non error
      at hic dolore aspernatur impedit dolorem similique incidunt pariatur! Atque adipisci fugiat aperiam qui excepturi doloremque, quaerat quisquam similique molestiae.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>div 3</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non error at Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non error at Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non error at Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
      elit. Non error at hic dolore aspernatur impedit dolorem similique incidunt pariatur! Atque adipisci fugiat aperiam qui excepturi doloremque, quaerat quisquam similique molestiae. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non error
      at hic dolore aspernatur impedit dolorem similique incidunt pariatur! Atque adipisci fugiat aperiam qui excepturi doloremque, quaerat quisquam similique molestiae.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>

<div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non error at Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non error at Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non error at Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
    elit. Non error at hic dolore aspernatur impedit dolorem similique incidunt pariatur! Atque adipisci fugiat aperiam qui excepturi doloremque, quaerat quisquam similique molestiae. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non error
    at hic dolore aspernatur impedit dolorem similique incidunt pariatur! Atque adipisci fugiat aperiam qui excepturi doloremque, quaerat quisquam similique molestiae.
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non error at Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non error at Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non error at Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
    elit. Non error at hic dolore aspernatur impedit dolorem similique incidunt pariatur! Atque adipisci fugiat aperiam qui excepturi doloremque, quaerat quisquam similique molestiae. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non error
    at hic dolore aspernatur impedit dolorem similique incidunt pariatur! Atque adipisci fugiat aperiam qui excepturi doloremque, quaerat quisquam similique molestiae.
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non error at Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non error at Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non error at Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
    elit. Non error at hic dolore aspernatur impedit dolorem similique incidunt pariatur! Atque adipisci fugiat aperiam qui excepturi doloremque, quaerat quisquam similique molestiae. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non error
    at hic dolore aspernatur impedit dolorem similique incidunt pariatur! Atque adipisci fugiat aperiam qui excepturi doloremque, quaerat quisquam similique molestiae.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non error at Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non error at Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non error at Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
    elit. Non error at hic dolore aspernatur impedit dolorem similique incidunt pariatur! Atque adipisci fugiat aperiam qui excepturi doloremque, quaerat quisquam similique molestiae. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non error
    at hic dolore aspernatur impedit dolorem similique incidunt pariatur! Atque adipisci fugiat aperiam qui excepturi doloremque, quaerat quisquam similique molestiae.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to control it with JS ,cause I want to sticky when the  tab header is in top of the browser not all the time

Comment: Your sandbox code is a mess, it's highly unreadable. Can you please share your actual code via github, if possible or explain your issue in more detail.